# WPF: Setting border on mouseover in a resource style

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I have this style as a resource in `App.xaml`

```
<Style x:Key="StackPanelLink" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="500" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="GhostWhite" />
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="LightBlue" />
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="10" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The background-changing trigger works but the border-changing one does not. All the examples I have seen online have used a Border element inside the `StackPanel` and I don't understand how to apply this to a style in a resource file.

Rant: So far I really hate WPF. It's about the least discoverable, least intuitive technology I have ever used. Every trivial thing I try to do is an hour of Googling and some solution involving like 30 lines of XML.

Comment: A StackPanel has no Border.BorderBrush/Border.BorderThickness to be set...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The background-changing trigger works but the border-changing one does not.

That's because these properties don't exist on the `StackPanel`. A `StackPanel` has no border. It's just a `Panel` that arranges child elements into a single line that can be oriented horizontally or vertically.

It sounds like you want to use a `Border` element and Style:

```
<Style x:Key="StackPanelLink" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="500" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="GhostWhite" />
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="LightBlue" />
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="10" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
...
<Border Style="{StaticResource StackPanelLink}">
    <TextBlock>....</TextBlock>
</Border>
```

Comment: OK thanks but... this is what I mean about unintuitive. Doesn't that completely wreck my separation of style and markup? I'm asking a styling question and your answer is "go edit your markup". Is this not in the same category of bad ideas as font, center, etc tags in HTML? Am I misunderstanding something fundamental?

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking. A Style for a StackPanel can *only* set properties of a StackPanel. And a StackPanel has no concept of a border. So yes, you should probably edit your markup by replacing the StackPanel with a Border if you really want a border.

Comment: I understand the answer, but border is a visual style, in the same category as Background, Foreground, Padding, Margin etc. It's not a control like Textbox, Label etc. The answer to "what does a Border do other than change the way it looks" is "nothing". I don't get why I have to add controls to my document in order to change very trivial visual styling. I guess most succinctly: WHY does StackPanel not have a border property? Other controls have borders. StackPanel has other style properties. It just seems like a bizarre inconsistency.

Comment: Because a StackPanel is a Panel and a Border is a decorator. Two different types. No panel in WPF has any concept of borders: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview